# ANTLR4-Mutually left-recursive grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar, antlr4, left-recursion

i have the following antlr4 grammar and i get mutually left-recursive error , how can i fix it ?

```
expr : expr_prefix term ;
expr_prefix : expr_prefix term addop
            | () ;
term : factor_prefix factor;
factor_prefix : factor_prefix factor mulop
              | () ;
factor : primary 
       | call_expr ;
primary : ( expr ) 
        | id
        | INTLITERAL
        | FLOATLITERAL ;
```

Comment: What is the actual error message? What parts are mutually left recursive?

Comment: this is exactly what i get : error <119> the following sets of rules are mutually left - recursive [ expr , primary , expr_prefix , term , factor_prefix , factor ]

Comment: They are multiple ways this can be fixed. I would start with `factor_prefix : factor_prefix` or `expr_prefix : expr_prefix `. It would help if you could update the question with examples of sentences this grammar has to accept and the ones it should reject